# How to deny application's access to network by AppArmor?

Tags: linux, debian, security, apparmor

Environment:

```
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch)
Kernel parameter: security=apparmor
```

Here is my test profile (created by aa-genprof):

/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.telnet.netkit

```
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/telnet.netkit {
  #include <abstractions/base>

  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-*.so mr,
  /usr/bin/telnet.netkit mr,

  deny network,
}
```

Take effect by:

```
sudo systemctl reload apparmor.service
```

AppArmor status:

```
$ sudo aa-status | grep telnet
   /usr/bin/telnet
   /usr/bin/telnet.netkit
```

But when I test the telnet program:

```
$ telnet.netkit 127.0.0.1 22
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u2
```

**Network access is NOT denied.**

Here is the process status:

```
$ ps auxZ | grep -v unconfined | grep telnet
/usr/bin/telnet.netkit (enforce) test    10410  0.0  0.0  19504  2852 pts/1    S+   18:26   0:00 telnet.netkit 127.0.0.1 22
```

Netstat:

```
$ netstat -nap | grep telnet
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56710         127.0.0.1:22            ESTABLISHED 10410/telnet.netkit
```

Can anyone help to find out what's wrong with the profile? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure `/usr/bin/telnet` is the actual binary?

Comment: Not able to reproduce in my `Ubuntu 16.04` `#/etc/apparmor.d$ cat usr.bin.telnet 
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/telnet {
  #include <abstractions/base>

  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-*.so mr,
  /usr/bin/telnet mr,

  deny network,
}`
`# /etc/apparmor.d$ sudo aa-status | grep tel
   /usr/bin/telnet`
`#/etc/apparmor.d$ telnet 127.0.0.1
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Comment: @Thushi /usr/bin/telnet.netkit is the actual binary. /usr/bin/telnet is a symbol link to the telnet.netkit. I see your test command "telnet 127.0.0.1" is without a port number, which will cause telnet connect to 127.0.0.1:23. Maybe port 23 is not listening in your system, so connection is refused by OS.

Comment: Yes, You are right! I am able to reproduce it now! Will check that. Thanks!

Comment: Found this: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/apparmor/2016-July/009835.html . This might help you, Looks like still these features are not enabled completely.

Comment: @Thushi Thanks for reproducing this problem and sharing the message. As the mail says, "There's currently no way to deny *specific* network operations", and "The best you can do is disable inet or inet6 entirely with the deny rules.",  means that the deny rule "deny network" is valid and should be worked, but actual is not. Maybe this problem is only existed in debian (and its derivatives) as Bigon says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading correctly you are running debian.

Well the problem is that the kernel in debian lacks of the needed code to block the network connections (same for D-Bus mitigation) as the patches are not mainline (yet, I know there was work to change the situation).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm using debian stretch. I added two kernel parameters "apparmor=1 security=apparmor" in the GRUB configuration file, is that not enough?

Comment: No, as said the kernel in debian is missing all the code that is doing network (and D-Bus) mediation, see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=712451

There was an attempt at merging the needed code upstream in 4.14, but it was (partially?) reverted due to regressions. I'm not sure what is the status of these patches today.